# How to add datarows to an already existing datatable?

Tags: c#, datatable

I am having an datatable which is already populated. Now i want to add few rows to that datatable ,but some of rows might already exist in the datatable.I know its unneccesary but tht is the requirement.

I tried couple of things and got "the row already exist in this table : & this row belongs to some other table" .I also tried importRow ,but i guess  it avoid the duplicates by dafault.

Is there any way to do that .If the datatable has 7 rows and i want to add 3 more rows whether its already exist or not. My goal is to send 10 rows  to the calling function .

Or is there any other approach altogether?

**UPDATE**

Using 
`rowsToAdd.CopyToDataTable(dsCount.Tables[2], LoadOption.PreserveChanges);` works but I'm not sure it's the proper way.

Comment: rowsToAdd.CopyToDataTable(dsCount.Tables[2], LoadOption.PreserveChanges); This is working ,but not sure whether its correct of doing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To check for any duplicates try

```
if (table.Rows.Contain(PriKeyTypeValue)) /*See if a Primary Key Value is in 
the table already */
    continue;
else
    table.Row.Add(value1, value2, value3);
```

If you want to be able to insert duplicate rows but do not want to have an exception thrown set-up your primary key as a unique self-incrementing int then you can insert as many duplicates as you feel like without having to check to see if the table contains that value. Just make sure that it would suffice to have duplicates. There are plenty of examples of setting a primary key just search for it (msdn has at least one). Here is an example:

```
DataTable table = new DataTable();

table.Columns.Add("Column", typeof(int));

DataColumn column = table.Columns["Column"];
column.Unique = true;
column.AutoIncrement = true;
column.AutoIncrementStep = 1; //change these to whatever works for you
column.AutoIncrementSeed = 1;
table.PrimaryKey = new DataColumn[] { column };
```

Comment: Thanks for the code. the below code is working,but i will try your suggestions. rowsToAdd.CopyToDataTable(dsCount.Tables[2], LoadOption.PreserveChanges);

Comment: The `table.Row.Add()` I used is not as robust as the code below since all the values need to be in the proper order or you might be placing the wrong data value into the table but it still should help with some idea's for you.

Answer (score 4):

You can add new rows in `DataTable` using code below

```
DataRow newRow = dataTable.NewRow();
dataTable.Rows.Add(newRow);
```

Answer (score 3):

Create a new row using the NewRow() function.

```
var dataTable = new DataTable();
var dataRow = dataTable.NewRow();
```

Then add your new row to your datatable

```
dataTable.Rows.Add(dataRow)
```

Comment: @The above code wont add already existing rows . My req is sometimes i need to add already existing rows to make the count .

Answer (score 1):

I believe you can use the NewRow() function of the DataTable if you're simply appending a row to the table.

```
DataTable table = new DataTable();    
DataRow row = table.NewRow();

table.Rows.Add(row);
```

Will that not suffice?

Comment: I don't think so that it will add row until you explicitly call `datatable.Rows.Add` method

Comment: @Haris Hasan: You're right about that part, and I've updated my answer. I think that doing it this way will work as long as they're aren't any unique constraints on his table though, right? Surely it will be more appropriate than ImportRow for what OP is trying to do, right?

Answer (score 0):

The most straightforward method. After spending a few hours trying everything else.

```
DataRow dr = ds.Tables[0].NewRow();
dr["ColumnName1"] = "columnvalue"; //string
dr["ColumnName2"] = 123 //int
ds.Tables[0].Rows.Add(dr);
```